# How to find the integral of this exponential function?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Does anyone know how to find the integral of this function? I've searched several tables of integrals, but I couldn't find anything similar.
$$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{{x{e^{ - {{{\omega ^2}} \over {4\alpha }} + \beta \,\omega }}} \over {1 - xy{e^{iL\omega }}}}d\omega } $$
where $x, y, L,$ and $\alpha $ are reals

Comment: Yes, certainly a necessary condition would be that $\alpha < 0$

Comment: You are right, I modified it, thank you.